# Problem with gb4e and macro for tabular with curly brackets

Tags: macros, linguistics, gb4e

When using the macro `\CurlyBrackets` at the beginning of a `gb4e` example, the example is not typeset as expected. Is there a better way to do this to get the desired output?

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\noautomath
\newcommand{\CurlyBrackets}[1]{%
    \vbox{%
        \hbox{$\left\{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}\right\}$}
    }
}%
\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
    \ex[\#]{\CurlyBrackets{A cat\\Seven dogs\\Mary} \CurlyBrackets{is\\are} widespread.}
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

### Desired output

[image]

Note that the desired output can be achieved by putting a non-breaking space at the beginning of the example, but I would prefer to not have to do this.

```
\ex[\#]{~\CurlyBrackets{A cat\\Seven dogs\\Mary} \CurlyBrackets{is\\are} widespread.}
```

Comment: Can you explain why you need the `\vbox` and `\hbox`? If you remove those, it looks fine to me.

Comment: @JasonZentz No, probably not. I think this is a macro that I copied and pasted from somewhere on this site a long time ago and have just been using ever since.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\vbox` doesn't start a paragraph:

```
\newcommand{\CurlyBrackets}[1]{%
    \leavevmode\vbox{
        \hbox{$\left\{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}\right\}$}
    }%
}
```

Full example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\noautomath

\newcommand{\CurlyBrackets}[1]{%
    \leavevmode\vbox{
        \hbox{$\left\{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}\right\}$}
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
    \ex[\#]{\CurlyBrackets{A cat\\Seven dogs\\Mary} \CurlyBrackets{is\\are} widespread.}
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, the following is simpler and doesn't suffer from that problem in the first place:

```
\newcommand{\CurlyBrackets}[1]{%
 $\left\{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}\right\}$%
}
```

Note: when you enclose this in an `\hbox` you get essentially the same thing, just wrapped up in the box, and the reference point of the formula will define the reference point for the outer box.

The construction `\vbox{\hbox{...}}` is pretty much equivalent to `\hbox{...}`: you're just adding a level of boxing. With `\vbox`, the *last* box (assuming there are just piled up boxes in it) will define the reference point (the general case is a bit more complicated).

So there's no advantage and no output difference between the two versions.

Note that you had two useless `%` characters, but were missing an important one.

Answer (score 2):

I can't explain the behavior, but taking out `\vbox` and `\hbox` from the definition of `\CurlyBrackets` gives the right result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\noautomath
\newcommand{\CurlyBrackets}[1]{%
    $\left\{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}\right\}$
}%
\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
    \ex[\#]{\CurlyBrackets{A cat\\Seven dogs\\Mary} \CurlyBrackets{is\\are} widespread.}
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 But I've accepted egreg's answer, since there is a bit more of an explanation.